# JS Draggable Viewport

Tags: jquery, draggable, viewport

I was wondering if it is at all possible to create a draggable viewport in JS. The idea is to have three DIVs layered on top of each other:

- Top layer is a draggable viewport that reveals the bottom-most DIV (image)
- Middle layer is a large image that covers the bottom DIV entirely
- Bottom layer is a large image that is hidden by the middle layer (apart from the bit in the viewport)

I've found many helpful libraries to make a draggable DIV, but am not so sure that it is possible to make it see through the middle layer to reveal the bottom layer.

EDIT: I've uploaded a diagram of what I mean - The viewport looks "through" the middle layer, at the bottom layer - [diagram](http://theflounderinghalibut.com/stuff/diagram.jpg)

Comment: description is ambiguous and hard to follow. Such as `Top layer ...reveals the bottom-most DIV `  while `middle layer...covers the bottom DIV entirely`. Need a better description of what is visible when

Comment: @charlietfl - Apologies for the ambiguousness; I've uploaded a (terrible) diagram of what I have in mind. I think the problem may have been that I forgot to mention that the viewport is smaller (200px square) than the other DIVs (1000px square).

Comment: yeah... viewport typically means the full screen ..diagram defintely helps. can middle layer image be moved without being noticeable and make it much larger than screen size? If so can do this with 2 layers only relatively easily by having a transperent section in middle image png file

Comment: @charlietfl - Thanks for your suggestion; it would work quite well but unfortunately the middle layer is a very detailed image, so it would be noticeable if it moved.

Comment: OK... then concept can be done , but gets quite complicated and will require some heavy calculations while moving. The middle image will have to be used as background image for many very small elements if you want to be able to look through it. Seamless smooth motion appearance will be tricky. Essentially as you move the top, backgrounds will have to be toggled on collections of the many small elements to create "transparency"

Comment: @charlietfl - Thanks again for another clever idea. Unfortunately, the motion would need to be somewhat seamless, and the thought of heavy calculations is rather daunting. I think I might change the project to either implement your first suggestion, or something else entirely. Thanks again.

Comment: last comment is backwards. Still do this with 2 layers, top `viewport` background would be bottom image and move background accordingly. Is not that difficult. There are even off the shelf plugins for this

Comment: @charlietfl - You are a genius. Thanks heaps! Would you be able to suggest any of those plugins, or what I should be searching for?

Comment: I've seen one or 2...but not even sure what to search for to be honest at this moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With many thanks to charlietfl, I have solved my problem. I've used the [JQuery UI Draggable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and dropped the number of layers down to two, simply adjusting the background position of the top DIV (#viewport) based on its own position.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="viewport"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 817px;
    background-image: url("assets/images/extras2/extras-top.jpg");
    position: relative;
}

#viewport {
    width: 338px;
    height: 235px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 20px;
    background-image: url("assets/images/extras2/extras-bottom.jpg");
    background-position: -300px -20px;
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#viewport").draggable({containment: "#container", scroll: false});
    $("#viewport").on("drag", function(){
        $(this).css("background-position", "-" + $(this).position().left + "px -" + $(this).position().top + "px")
    });
});
```